# EECP (Enhanced External Counterpulsation) therapy v/s Angioplasty and Bypass surgery

Tags: heart-disease, angioplasty, coronary-bypass

I have read some article about [**EECP (Enhanced External Counterpulsation) therapy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_counterpulsation) for the treatment of angina and some doctors even saying that it must be suggested as the first option and others doesn't seem to completely agree with that.

How effective is EECP compared to angioplasty and Bypass ?

Will it really be considered as an alternative to the other two methods ?

Why it is not that popular as other methods ?

Comment: 'd appreciate if someone experienced with these methods 'd comment.

Comment: i hope some one s aware of this method here !!